# how to add navigation drawer top to bottom in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

This is the image of design that are given in link. i want open drawer from top to Bottom

`drawer: Drawer(),`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPuRT.png

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please explain.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPuRT.png please open this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to drawer to slide from top to bottom, you might want to use a `SlideTransition()`.

Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59464729/how-to-make-top-navigation-drawer-with-flutter) for more info.